# How to intercept a non SSL connection in onAuthorization method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4, ASP.NET 4.5, C#

I want to add code to my onAuthorization method in global.asa to identify whether the connection is SSL or not, if not then to issue a permanent redirect to a SSL domain. I am using another domain that is SSLed.

In my Login controller I have code along the lines of :

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult LogOn(string Error="")
{
if (Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            return View(viewModel);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectPermanent("https://www.mysslapp.com/logon");
        }
}
```

I want to add this same functionality to the onAuthorization method so that when actions, covered by the [authorize] filter are called then they must also be accessed by a SSL connection. So I believe my global.asa code needs changing. However it will not accept "Request.IsSecureConnection", as the context is different.

My "pseudo" Global.asa onAuthorization routine is:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{

  if (Request.IsSecureConnection) 
    {
      base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
  else
    {
      RedirectPermanent("https://www.mysslapp.com/logon");
    }

}
```

The above will not work, but it describes what I am trying to achieve. I would appreciate help on how I need to change the above code to make it work, such that any "adventurous" use of urls, on a non SSL connection will automatically redirect to the SSL site logon page.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT1

Think I have the first bit:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection
```

EDIT2

```
if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection)
  {
    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
  }
else
  {      
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("https://www.mysslapp.com");
  }
```

Comment: Your use case is a bit confusing. SSL is not the same as IsAuthenticated. Normally, you use `AuthorizeAttribute` to determine if a user is logged in (and in the right role) and if not, deny the request. Normally, when you want to redirect from `HTTP` to `HTTPS`, you use the same path that the user requested. Then, if the user needs to login the `AuthorizeAttribute` will reject the request and MVC will append the `returnUrl` to the query string so when the user logs in they go to the URL they requested. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I decided to use a completely seperate domain for SSL, as I am using Cloudflare, for SSL and other security features. In addition I wish the old non ssl domain to continue to route to non application sales pages. The application used to use app.nonssl.com. So I want to reroute to "mysslapp.com" if connection non ssl, ie if they come to my site via "app.nonssl.com". I do not want to do it just on the login page, I need to prevent non ssl access on all actions, and it seemed to me that putting the code in the "onAuthorization" method would do the trick.

Comment: I have since added code and it does work, as per EDIT2. Although I am not sure how to do a permanent redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main issue is that you have 2 separate concerns and you are trying to achieve both in one go. Your 2 concerns are:

1. Making every URL of domain A 301 redirect to the same URL on domain B
2. Making domain B redirect all requests to HTTPS

The first one is really easy. Create a new IIS site for domain A, install the [IIS rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite), add this web.config to the site, and then adjust your DNS (if necessary) to make the site live.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect 
            enabled="true" 
            destination="https://www.mysslapp.com$V$Q" 
            exactDestination="true" 
            httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
        <httpProtocol>
            <redirectHeaders>
                <!-- This is to ensure that clients don't cache the 301 itself - 
                this is dangerous because the 301 can't change when put in place 
                once it is cached -->
                <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache"/>
            </redirectHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

> NOTE: The above configuration is for IIS 7.5. I am not sure if it will work on other versions of IIS.

Now none of the users of domain B will incur the performance hit of the redirect rule, so all is good.

For redirecting your users of domain B to HTTPS, you should not use 301. Why? Because not all browsers respond to 301.

You should also not *only* allow HTTPS on the domain, but allow both HTTP and HTTPS. Why? Because your users that type `myssldomain.com` will get an ugly error message instead of a fast redirect to you HTTPS protected site.

So the simple solution to making your whole site redirect to HTTPS is to use the [RequireHttps](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/RequireHttpsAttribute.cs) attribute and register it as a global filter. The `RequireHttpsAttribute` uses a 302 redirect when a request comes in that is not secure.

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

As for the `AuthorizeAttribute`, you should leave that out of the equation altogether unless you need some customization that deals with **authorization**.

Comment: Thanks for this very comprehensive answer. I should have stated that I deploy into Azure Web Apps, so I do think I can alter IIS per se. Also interesting to pick up your recommendation not to use a 301 redirect which instinctively I was a little worried about.